# "this" inside prototype takes window instead of object

Tags: javascript, prototype, q

I created an Object called Survey and added a prototype function to it, and when I console log this inside the prototype function the log shows window object instead of parent Survey Object.

```
function Survey(questions = []) {
  this.__questions__ = questions;
};
Survey.prototype.testFunction = () => {
  console.log(this);
  return this.__questions__;
}
// Create your object here
const SUR = new Survey(['1','2']);

SUR.testFunction(); // this prints [[Window]] Object instead of Survey
```

Expected result would be Survey object

Comment: when you use an arrow function you are changing the way the this keyword is bound, use a normal function instead "Survey.prototype.testFunction = function () {"

Comment: It's because you're using an array function. Array function don't have a this-context so they will use the this-context from outside. (In this case global/window)

Comment: **this** is explained in the doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions `although without its own bindings to the this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you used an [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
In arrow function, `this` will be reference to outside. Just use a normal function instead.

```
Survey.prototype.testFunction = function() {
  console.log(this);
  return this.__questions__;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is over here:

```
Survey.prototype.testFunction = () => {}
```

Arrow functions don't have a this-context and it will use the this-context from outside of the method. Since no other this-context is defined, it will be the window object.

The fix is very easy: use a regular function:

```
Survey.prototype.testFunction = function () {}
```